# Java: simple program to attach document or image

Tags: java

I have two buttons and one textset on [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). I need the first button to allow the user to browse for files and the second button to attach documents or images and displayed in textset.

Comment: Can you show what you have implemented so far? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to find the image on the hard drive and you can display the image on a [JLabel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)